# How to create JPG file in RawTherapee without changing original RAW

Tags: image-processing

With RawTherapee 4.2, I want to edit the image and export it as jpg file, but without touching the original RAW file. Is it possible? At the moment I copy the RAW, edit it and put it to the queue to create a jpeg. Then i delete the copied raw file.

Answer (score 1):

An export doesn't change the original file. Therefore it's named <kbd>Export</kbd>. To check this

1. Create a copy of your RAW file
2. Open RawTherapee and export as JPG
3. Check the modification type of your copied RAW file via `stat`

   *Example*

   I create a new file named `foo` via `touch` and do some things.
   Check the output of the command `stat`, especially `Access`, `Modify` and `Change` to become an idea

   ```
   % touch foo
   % stat foo
     File: ‘foo’
     Size: 0           Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
   Device: 2eh/46d Inode: 393375      Links: 1
   Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/aboettger)   Gid: ( 1000/aboettger)
   Access: 2015-08-26 14:09:33.747255155 +0200
   Modify: 2015-08-26 14:09:33.747255155 +0200
   Change: 2015-08-26 14:09:33.747255155 +0200
    Birth: -

   % echo foobar > foo
   % stat foo
     File: ‘foo’
     Size: 7           Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
   Device: 2eh/46d Inode: 393375      Links: 1
   Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/aboettger)   Gid: ( 1000/aboettger)
   Access: 2015-08-26 14:09:33.747255155 +0200
   Modify: 2015-08-26 14:09:41.799215458 +0200
   Change: 2015-08-26 14:09:41.799215458 +0200
    Birth: -

   % less foo
   % stat foo
     File: ‘foo’
     Size: 7           Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
   Device: 2eh/46d Inode: 393375      Links: 1
   Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/aboettger)   Gid: ( 1000/aboettger)
   Access: 2015-08-26 14:09:46.627191656 +0200
   Modify: 2015-08-26 14:09:41.799215458 +0200
   Change: 2015-08-26 14:09:41.799215458 +0200
    Birth: -
   ```